# flip the whole layout onclick button then show another activity

Tags: android-layout, android-animation, flip

I have many buttons on my activity and I need to flip the whole layout once a single button was clicked.The button that was clicked must show a specific activity which is clickable also with flip.

Help me here...

Note: I've seen a lot of tutorials online but they only flip the single image. thanks

Answer (score 0):

A flip activity is basically a rotation at Y axis. You can achieve it via `ObjectAnimator`.

```
ObjectAnimator anim=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourView, "rotationY", 360);
```

In case you work with **API Level** below **11** you need to use **Nine-old-androids** library since new **Animation API** which includes `ObjectAnimator`, `ValueAnimator` and a couple more became available with **API Level 11** and above.
Refer to the lib;
http://nineoldandroids.com/